# How to set up yaws-1.89 in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, yaws

I need help with setting up yaws-1.89 in ubuntu. This is the error I get:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 3-Dec-2010::16:52:40 ===
Yaws: Using config file /home/hudson2010/yaws.conf

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Dec-2010::16:52:40 ===
Config Warning: Directory /var/yaws/ebin for ebin_dir doesn't exist

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Dec-2010::16:52:40 ===
Yaws: bad conf: Unexpected tokens "max_connections" at line 30 terminating

=INFO REPORT==== 3-Dec-2010::16:52:40 ===
    application: yaws
    exited: {shutdown,{yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: permanent
```

Comment: I think this belongs at superuser.

Comment: There's some necroposting going on here..

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Yaws?

I also had problems when I installed it using `apt-get install yaws`. Instead I downloaded the latest stable build, Yaws 1.89, compiled it and then installed it on my Ubunut Server.

See my answer to [How to configure yaws webserver in the Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220134/how-to-configure-yaws-webserver-in-the-linux-terminal/5368351#5368351)

Answer (score 0):

Issue the following command in terminal:

```
$ which yaws
```

If you get something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

Then you should start yaws using sudo command:

```
$ sudo yaws
```