# How to configure yaws webserver in the linux terminal?

Tags: yaws

can someone help me on to write my yaws webserver configuration file in the Linux terminal. when i follow the yaws tutorials i get errors. thanks a lot.

Comment: What errors do you get? What commands do you run?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I installed **Yaws 1.89** on **Ubuntu Server 10.10**.

### 1. Update your Ubuntu system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

### 2. Install the tools you need to compile

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev
```

### 3. Download, compile and install Yaws 1.89

```
wget http://yaws.hyber.org/download/yaws-1.89.tar.gz
tar xfz yaws-1.89.tar.gz
cd yaws
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

Comment: You can more generally use `apt-get build-dep yaws` to install the dependencies you need in order to build Yaws.

Comment: `apt-get build-dep yaw` fails with the below error : `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`